# C# Directory.GetFiles() only showing one file in the list?

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn C#, I am starting with some simple stuff.

I am trying to create a simple program that will read all files in a directory which are .XLS extension. I seem to have it working partially, but it only reads the file it sees.

I thought the `foreach` statement would take care for this and list them all but it doesn't seem to work.

If anyone could put me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetFiles();
    }

    private void GetFiles()
    {
        List<String> Myfiles = new List<string>();
        string[] allFiles = System.IO.Directory
                            .GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\STUFF", "*.*");

        if (allFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string filename in allFiles)
                {
                    this.richTextBox1.Text = filename.ToString();
                }
            }   

            catch (SystemException excpt)
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Text = excpt.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You overwrite the filename each time you do this `this.richTextBox1.Text = filename.ToString();`, you probably want to append it or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter file for `xls`:

```
string[] allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\STUFF", "*.xls");
```

and update your try block code as :

```
   try
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text= string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allFiles);
            //foreach (string filename in allFiles)
            //{
           //     this.richTextBox1.Text = filename.ToString();

            //}
        }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, will accept when I can, Just a quick question, I'm assuming the way you have provided is the way to read an array properly?

Comment: If it helped then you should accept it. you can use folder dialog box to browse folder and read path from there.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want xls files, update this line:

```
string[] allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\STUFF", "*.xls");
```

You see probably one file in the edit box. Therefore, update the line:

```
this.richTextBox1.AppendText(filename + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be caused by this line:
`this.richTextBox1.Text = filename.ToString();`

You're essentially overwriting the text of the textbox each time, causing only the last filename being written to the `richtextbox`. You should be appending the filename string to the `richTextBox` rather than assigning.

Answer (score 0):

from a quick look I think your issue is here:

```
this.richTextBox1.Text = filename.ToString();
```

you are assigning the text property with the last loop iteration rather than appending a new line for each file.

try to debug the for loop, do you have multiple iterations?